# Delphi 10.2: TNetHttpRequest формирование заголовков

Tags: delphi, http

Я посылаю из Delphi приложения http post запросы используя компонент на форме TNetHttpRequest. Все CustomHeaders какие нужно выставляю. Но мне еще нужно как-то сформировать тело запроса, потому что в нем нужно передать аргументы - в самом простом виде "0 1 2". Нужно чтобы в итоге пакет имел примерно такой формат (вставка из сниффера):

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /setswitchport?section=STAT HTTP/1.1\r\n
    [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /setswitchport?section=STAT HTTP/1.1\r\n]
        [POST /setswitchport?section=STAT HTTP/1.1\r\n]
        [Severity level: Chat]
        [Group: Sequence]
    Request Method: POST
    Request URI: /setswitchport?section=STAT
        Request URI Path: /setswitchport
        Request URI Query: section=STAT
            Request URI Query Parameter: section=STAT
    Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Accept: */*\r\n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n
    Referer: http://192.168.10.30/\r\n
    Accept-Language: ru-RU\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\r\n
    Host: 192.168.10.30\r\n
        Content-Length: 3\r\n
            [Content length: 3]
        DNT: 1\r\n
        Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
        Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
        \r\n
        [Full request URI: http://192.168.10.30/setswitchport?section=STAT]
        [HTTP request 3/3]
        [Prev request in frame: 113]
        [Response in frame: 142]
        File Data: 3 bytes
HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Form item: "0 2" = ""
        Key: 0 2
        Value:
```

Особо интересует формирование последнего заголовка.

Comment: А в заголовки добавляли ('key','value')?

Comment: Нет. Как в данном случае это нужно добавить? Вот мой код:

Comment: with (NetHTTPRequest1) do
begin
MethodString := 'post';
URL := 'http://192.168.1.10/' + 'setswitchport?section=none%0 1';
CustomHeaders['Content-Type'] := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
CustomHeaders['X-Requested-With'] := 'XMLHttpRequest';
CustomHeaders['Accept-Encoding'] := 'gzip, deflate';
CustomHeaders['Accept-Language'] := 'ru-RU';
CustomHeaders['Referer'] := 'http://' + fIPAddress + '/';
CustomHeaders['Content-Length'] := '3';
try
Execute();
except
end;
end;

Comment: Используйте метод [Post](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.Post), который принимает TMultipartFormData (соответственно, вам нужно создать этот объект и [добавить](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Net.Mime.TMultipartFormData.AddField) в него данные для отправки).

Comment: Спасибо! Это похоже то что надо.

Answer (score 0):

*Под рукой Delphi нет, беру куски кода из старого проекта в облаке, часть пишу по памяти, где-то могу ошибиться.*
Я в тех немногих случаях, когда было необходимо получать/отправлять данные не через браузер, а в программе, поступал так:

```
var
  iHTTPR: TNetHTTPRequest;
  MyH: TNetHeaders;
  MyContent: TStream;
  MyResponse:IHTTPResponse;
  BLASTURI:string = 'https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi#<кусь-кусь>';

  procedure CreateHeaderData(Key, Value: String; var fH: TNetHeaders); inline;
// сервисная функция, сделанная для удобства. Можно улучшить :)
  begin
    SetLength(fH, Length(fH)+1);
    fH[Length(fH)-1].Name:=Key;
    fH[Length(fH)-1].Value:=Value;
  end;


Заполняем наши заголовки по образцу как у вас:

CreateHeaderData('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)', MyH);
CreateHeaderData('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', MyH);

// и так далее
// плюс, добавляем нужные ключи так же (у вас они будут другие):

CreateHeaderData('API-key', CalcThreadData.PAPIKey, MyH);
CreateHeaderData('API-public-certificate', CalcThreadData.GenerateCert, MyH);

// теперь отдаём это нашему TNetHTTPReques:

MyResponse:=iHTTPR.Options(BLASTURI, MyContent, myH);

// дальше разбираем полученные данные
```

Comment: Да это понятно, но... при таком подходе Content-Length остается нулевым и не появляется вот этот раздел "HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"